# How to add security related headers in tomcat 9

Tags: web-server, tomcat, http

I want to add several security related HTTP response headers with tomcat(version 9). I have enabled following config in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now I get following headers in http response.
[image]

Furthermore I would like to have following headers also.

- referrer-policy
- x-permitted-cross-domain-policies
- permission-policy (or feature-policy)

How can I add these header to the http response?